# Convert symbolic expression to double

Tags: matlab, substitution

I have the following symbolic expression (in Matlab)

```
syms k l
dk = 1/(k+l);
```

Then I do some symbolic algebra. Finally I'd like to calcute some numeric values and actually need

```
dk = 1./(k+l);
```

How can I get the expression with a dot afterwards?

Comment: What language is this?